# Atheros AR9485 vs Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, atheros

I've read a lot of threads about in the forum but none of them solved my problem. I have got a AR9485 that works perfectly but if the net ask for a password. WEP, WAP... everything that make me to log in, automatically put me out of range from that net and set my card in blank.

If I try to connect a no-secure WiFi I get no problem at all.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```